# How to display a list of Firebase users excluding the logged-in user in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Currently, I have a **SteamBuilder** fetching data from a "user" collection

```
return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data.documents[index];

            // else
            return user.uid == document['uid']
                ? null //null should not be returned but the user should be excluded in the below ListTile
                // this is causing only the users up to the logged-in user to display and then terminating without rendering other widgets

                : ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    title: Text(
                      document['name'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                    ),
                  );
          });
    },
  ),
```

What logic should I implement so I exclude the logged-in user from rendering but display all others, can I pass a where() to the snapshot?

Comment: So you want to display all the non-logged in users?

Comment: I want to display all the users except the currently logged in user, I have created a document for each user  in a collection('user').   I learned that != operator cannot be used in the where( ) method because it does not scale well. So changed have to be done locally. So I'm trying to do it without complicating the widget tree insde Listview.builder() too much.

Comment: Okay, I somehow figured out a dirty way of accomplishing the task. I added a bool = false variable and created a list. Added the snapshots to list at first and then added a conditional if(user.uid == document['uid'] bool = true. Then built bool? Contianer(height: 0): ListTile()

Comment: Sorry I have been offline. Sometimes it can get ugly to accomplish some complex features but perhaps you may be able to make a compound query that allows you to  see who is currently logged in. I am not sure how you are checking to see who is and isn't logged in but you can utilize 2 `.where()` queries. For example, `db.where("age", "<", "30").where("age", ">", 30)`. This will give you the same results as a not equal query. Not sure if this is applicable to your example above but may lead you in the right direction

Comment: Instead of null return empty container(), as empty won't take up any space.

Comment: @AnthonySette, I did try Chaining the .where( ) method but the stream would not return anything in that case. It was returning an empty stream, hence I read somewhere that it was better to do the operation locally and so I did the above.

Comment: @Harshapulikollu, yes that's what I've done and mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am facing the same problem but here is the solution in below sample code I hope this will work for you.

```
return ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                  height: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['id'] != uid
                      ? 70.0
                      : 0.0, // this line for hiding specific cell...
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(snapshot
                                  .data.documents[index].data['nickname']))
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
              return snapshot.data.documents[index].data['id'] != uid
                  ? Divider()
                  : Container(); // this line hide the devider for specific cell..
            },
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length);
```

Comment: Hey, this was a long time ago and I did something similar I believe, but this works as well I suppose in was skipping  a listile when I had a matching user id I guess. Anyway I'll accept your answer.